# How to cite an Amazon page product?

Tags: citations

We are supposed to cite product's pages on Amazon (to cite the price).

Which informations are we supposed to put in the bibliography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like you would any other web reference with both a link and a date on which the link was accessed by you. This guards against changes that can always occur in any web resource. You can take the title from the page title.

The date is essential.

Comment: For the author, is it Amazon?

Comment: Probably, but for some things maybe something from the page, such as a book's author. Hard to say in general. You could omit author in favor of a descriptive.